# NET 6 JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync pass null value to non-nullable property

Tags: asp.net, json, .net

I am using JsonSerializer to Deserialize a post request from a client. The class for serialization contains non-null and required properties. The Json serializer ignores the constructor and the non-null types and passes it the null value.

Current: non-nullable fields sets as null
Expected: throw an exception

How can I fix this? Maybe there is some attribute or parameter

```json
{
    "time": [250, 500, 1000]
}
```

```cs
[Serializable]
public class ArchiveData
{

    [JsonConstructor]
    public ArchiveData(long[] time, SensorArchiveValues[] sensorsArchiveValues)
    {
        Time = time;
        SensorsArchiveValues = sensorsArchiveValues;
    }

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public long[] Time { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SensorArchiveValues[] SensorsArchiveValues { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: you marked SensorsArchiveValues as required, but I can't see any SensorsArchiveValues in your json. Pls post the valid json

Comment: This is valid json, that's the problem, that it's valid, but it shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

it is better to fix the class, but if you can not change it , try this code

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json).Dump();

    long[] time = jsonParsed["time"].ToObject<long[]>();
    SensorArchiveValues[] sensorsArchiveValues = null;

    if (jsonParsed["sensorsArchiveValues"] != null) 
    sensorsArchiveValues = jsonParsed["sensorsArchiveValues"].ToObject<SensorArchiveValues[]>();
    
    // and maybe
   // else sensorsArchiveValues =  Array.Empty<SensorArchiveValues>();
   
    var archiveData = new ArchiveData(time,sensorsArchiveValues);
```